# How to fetch between a range in tastypie?

Tags: django, python-3.x, tastypie

I am trying to create an app in tastypie. From the tutorials i saw we can fetch data by their id using set. Like,

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/set/1;3/"
```

But this will bring only data 1 and 3. Can i fetch 1 to 3 in tastypie? Is there any functionalities implemented for that?

Edit:

```
class OrganisationResource(ModelResource):
    create_user = fields.ForeignKey(PersonResource, 'create_user', null=True, full=True)
    update_user = fields.ForeignKey(PersonResource, 'update_user', null=True, full=True)
    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource, 'location', null=True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post','get','delete','patch','put']
        queryset = Organization.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'organisation'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        filtering = {"id": ALL}
        always_return_data = True
```